# Identify a short story where two astronauts on an orbiting platform are having a dispute

Tags: story-identification, gravity, orbital-mechanics

I remember reading a short story in the 60/70's where there were two astronauts in spacesuits on an orbiting platform having some sort of dispute. One of them successfully threatens the other to by hurling him towards the planet whereby he believes that he doomed to keep falling. It turns out, however, that following orbital mechanics ( conservation of the center of gravity ) that the hapless astronaut will rejoin the platform halfway through the revolution. I thought this was a Clark or Asimov since it involved some real physics but I can't seem to locate the title.

Comment: I doubt this Clark, Asimov or Heinlein because it would be very difficult to make this actually work.  Oxygen consumption during the trip being a key part.  Even with lots of O2 is difficult to imagine the physics (sans thrust by body) that would return a body to a orbiting station, where it received an outward/planet side push.

Comment: @JamesJenkins As a matter of fact, Clarke did write a short story with the exact same plot twist: [Jupiter Five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Five), though the wikipedia synopsis doesn't describe this part. In short, the good guys hurl the bad guy out from the Jovian moon Amalthea, which successfully threatens him and his team into submission; then it's revealed that the bad guy needs no saving, as he'll just come back at the next revolution. I also recall Clarke saying that the physics of it are sound.

Comment: @JamesJenkins If this was in low earth orbit, the rendezvous would be ~45 minutes or 90 if it took 1 revolution. I would assume there would be enough O2. The notion is that since both bodies were part of a single mass and then pushed apart by a common force, they have to intersect again at a period related to the orbital period. If the bodies were pushed apart in such a way (tangentially) that they had different tangential velocities, They would end up indefinitely apart in an upper and lower orbit.

Comment: @SáT I bet that's the story the OP is looking for, maybe you should post it as an answer.

Comment: The physics is sound to first order, but there are higher order perturbations, so you need some means to grab the victim on closest approach which will be reasonably close, but not exact. Nor, to first order, does it matter in which direction the victim is pushed, the orbits are still nearly intersecting on one full orbit (but *not* on a half orbit).

Comment: @SAT and dmckee Thanks Good leads here and I'm pretty sure I read Sentinel after I read Rendezvous with Rama so that might be the one. I might buy another copy. It would be great to find an orbital simulator on line that could demonstrate the principles involved. I love physics and the periodic intersecting orbits make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @SáT I found a complete copy of Jupiter Five in Google books in the Collected Stories of Arthur C. Clarke. I read the whole yarn (again). This was the one I was trying to remember. It was memorable for the principle (the plot situation was somewhat less memorable). I was trying to find it after seeing some trailers from the movie Gravity (haven't seen it yet) and wondering if it had any relevance. Thank you for your swift answer! I think I'll be visiting this site more often in the future and may buy the anthology.

Comment: @Wayne Haha, awesome! tbh I didn't actually think this was the one you're looking for, I figured the archeology aspect was pretty memorable. Anyway, glad you found it. And yes, I agree, the short story is not very awesome, Clarke himself wasn't very fond of the pulp fiction aspect (generally quite uncharacteristic of him).

Comment: SaT - In the story the man does not come back to exactly where he started - just close. The narrator says "We hauled Mays down about an hour later. He was only about twenty kilometers up, and we located him quickly enough by the flashing light on his suit"

Comment: see OP confirmation comment above

Comment: @Wayne Please 'accept' the answer that was helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like Clarke's "Jupiter Five".

The Satellite in Question (we call it "Amalthea" now) has turned out to be be a giant spaceship built by an extinct alien race, and two rival expeditions learn this at the same time. One of them steals a valuable artifact from the other, who retaliate by throwing its leader into Jupiter - secure in the knowledge  that in one orbit he'll be back where he started and can be picked up.

The story was anthologised in *Reach For Tomorrow* [and no doubt elsewhere](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56728).